# Is this a valid SQL conditional expression or a MySQL bug (feature)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to debug some joins which seemed to returning cartesian products I typed the equivalent ON condition into selects.

In MySQL

```
select * 
from table 
where columnname
```

seems to behave as though I typed `where columname is not null`. In joins typing `on table.columnname` is accepted but returns LOTS of rows. MySQL does the right thing if I correct it to `on table1.column=table2.column` but surely my first version was incorrect and illegal.

Comment: Presumably it casts the value in `columnname` to boolean and returns those rows where it evaluates to true.

Comment: @MartinSmith: MySQL does not have a real boolean datatype. It simply treats every number that is not zero as true. Therefor `delete from foo where 42` will happily delete all rows in your table without complaining about the invalid syntax.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - What about for strings? Are they always treated as `false` except for `'1'`? Seems to be the case from [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c252c/2)

Comment: @MartinSmith: MySQL tries to convert them to a number: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/394f8/1

Comment: @MartinSmith: It seems strings are first converted to `INT`.

Comment: `where columnname` is not a syntax error, it's just a "logic error" :-)

Comment: @MartinSmith strings are casted to ints, `delete from foo where '1abc'` will delete all rows, while `delete from foo where 'abc'` won't

Comment: @fthiella - Nice example! I'd forgotten about that MySQL behaviour when converting non numeric strings.

Answer (score 2):

The contexts you are talking about, the `WHERE` clause and the `ON` clause in a join, simply accept an expression.

```
SELECT ...
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON <expr>
WHERE <expr>
```

Expressions can include comparison operators like `=` but expressions can also be as simple as a single column or a single constant value.

Compare with another context that accepts an expression: the select-list.

```
SELECT <expr>, <expr>, <expr>
```

It's normal to use a single column as the expression in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Most programming languages consider all values other than null, 0, '', false as true.
while(1); is an infinite loop irrespective of whether you give 1,2,'a',true and so on. I would say its a default expected behaviour and I have often used similar where clause

Comment: Specifically, in SQL null is implicitly cast to false when referenced as a condition.